# Paraview python 'Zoom to Box'

Tags: paraview, pvpython

I am trying to make a **script** which does basically what tool **'Zoom to Box'** does. Track option is out of question as it doesn't track camera movement.

[I've found this online](https://www.paraview.org/pipermail/paraview/2012-March/024352.html), fixed it to work, but keep getting '3d cam position is yet TODO' This is very old and maybe there are new options to do this? Thanks for the tips...

I could also try doing it by using classic camera commands like:

```
source=GetActiveSource()
#view = GetRenderView()
#view.CameraFocalPoint = [1, 0, 0]
#view.CameraViewAngle = 90
#view.CameraViewUp = [0, 0, 0]
#view.CameraPosition = [0, 0, 0]
#view.ViewSize = [1528, 542]
#view.ResetCamera()
```

But I'm not sure there is a way to zoom?

Fixed script from [the link](https://www.paraview.org/pipermail/paraview/2012-March/024352.html) above:

```
source=GetActiveSource()
rep = Show(source)

# run the pipeline here to get the bounds
Render()

bounds = source.GetDataInformation().GetBounds()
bounds_dx = bounds[1] - bounds[0]
bounds_dy = bounds[3] - bounds[2]
bounds_dz = bounds[5] - bounds[4]
bounds_cx = (bounds[0] + bounds[1])/2.0
bounds_cy = (bounds[2] + bounds[3])/2.0
bounds_cz = (bounds[4] + bounds[5])/2.0

if bounds_dx == 0:
# yz
    dimMode = 2
    aspect = bounds_dz/bounds_dy

elif bounds_dy == 0:
# xz
    dimMode = 1
    aspect = bounds_dz/bounds_dx

elif bounds_dz == 0:
# xy
    dimMode = 0
    aspect = bounds_dy/bounds_dx

else:
# 3d
    dimMode = 3
    aspect = 1.0  # TODO

lastObj = source

view = GetRenderView()
# view.ViewTime = steps[step] # unwanted
# view.UseOffscreenRenderingForScreenshots = 0 # obsolete

rep = Show(lastObj)
# rep.Representation = 'Outline' # unwanted
Render()

# position the camera
# far  = config.camFac
far = 1
near = 0

if dimMode == 0:
   # xy
    pos = max(bounds_dx, bounds_dy)
    camUp = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
    camPos = [bounds_cx, bounds_cy,  pos*far]
    camFoc = [bounds_cx, bounds_cy, -pos*near]

elif dimMode == 1:
   # xz
    pos = max(bounds_dx, bounds_dz)
    camUp = [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
    camPos = [bounds_cx, -pos*far,  bounds_cz]
    camFoc = [bounds_cx,  pos*near, bounds_cz]

elif dimMode == 2:
   # yz
    pos = max(bounds_dy, bounds_dz)
    camUp = [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
    camPos = [ pos*far, bounds_cy, bounds_cz]
    camFoc = [-pos*near, bounds_cy, bounds_cz]

else:
   # 3d
    print('3d cam position is yet TODO')
    camUp=[0,0,0]
    camPos=[1,0,0]
    camFoc=[0,0,0]

view = GetRenderView()
view.CameraViewUp = camUp
view.CameraPosition = camPos
view.CameraFocalPoint = camFoc
#view.UseOffscreenRenderingForScreenshots = 0 # obsolete
view.CenterAxesVisibility = 0

ren = Render()

#width = int(config.outputWidth)
#height = int(config.outputWidth*aspect)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just went ahead and did it this way:

```
import sys
from paraview.simple import *

# Camera Position
# positional coordinates of the camera
# zoom is achieved by adjusting x, y, z values (moving camera closer/further away) depending on focal point
# e. g. [10,0,4] - camera will be looking at object from this coordinate
CamPos = sys.argv[1]

# Camera Focal Point
# point of interest for the camera
# the point will be in the center of the screen and camera will rotate towards him in its position
# e. g. [0,0,0] - camera will focus its center on this coordinate
CamFocPoint = sys.argv[2]

# Camera View Up
# defining which way is up in the view
# uses values <-1;1> for each vector component
# to achieve angled view, use same value '1' for two vector components
# e. g. [0,0,1] - achieves having highest z component at the top
CamViewUp = sys.argv[3]

# getting active view
camera = GetActiveCamera()

# setting based on user definition
camera.SetPosition(CamPos[0], CamPos[1], CamPos[2])
camera.SetFocalPoint(CamFocPoint[0], CamFocPoint[1], CamFocPoint[2])
camera.SetViewUp(CamViewUp[0], CamViewUp[1], CamViewUp[2])

# making sure angle is right
camera.SetViewAngle(30)

# rendering view
Render()
```